# Where to find Organic Nutrients for +3 Kindness

Tags: persona-5

So I've been playing Persona 5 and following a guide. It tells me to buy Organic Nutrients from the Flower Shop in Shibuya. I went to the flower shop, but they only carry Bio Nutrients which only gives +2 to Kindness.

I thought this might be an error on the Editor's part but come to find out the item actually exists. Here's the problem: the flower shop doesn't even sell Organic Nutrients!

Looked online and no one can point me anywhere. Does anybody know where I can find Organic Nutrients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not called Organic Nutrients in English, it's called **Mega** Nutrients. It is also not in Shibuya, but in **Shinjuku**. From [this GameFAQs thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835628-persona-5/75209452):

> It's called Mega instead of Organic in English and it's in Shinjuku, not Shibuya (in case anyone searches)
>
> You buy them in the Flower Shop in the Red Light District in Shinjuku, not the underground mall.